# Implement useSelector equivalent for React Context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

There's a bunch of articles out there that show how Redux can be replaced with context and hooks (see [this one from Kent Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react), for instance). The basic idea is to make your global state available through a context instead of putting it inside a Redux store. But there's one big problem with that approach: components that subscribe to the context will be rerendered whenever any change happens to the context, regardless of whether or not your component cares about the part of the state that just changed. For functional components, React-redux solves this problem with the [useSelector hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector). So my question is: can a hook like useSelector be created that would grab a piece of the context instead of the Redux store, would have the same signature as useSelector, and, just like useSelector, would only cause rerenders to the component when the "selected" part of the context has changed?

(note: [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156) on the React Github page suggests that it can't be done)

Comment: Try [use-context-selector](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector), which seems to be doing what you want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Any time you put a new context value into a provider, *all* consumers will re-render, even if they only need part of that context value.

That's [specifically one of the reasons why we gave up on using context to propagate state updates in React-Redux v6, and switched back to using direct store subscriptions in v7](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/).

There's [a community-written React RFC to add selectors to context](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/119), but no indication the React team will actually pursue implementing that RFC at all.

Comment: Thank you for the authoritative answer, much appreciated. I'll definitely have to go through your article on the history of React-Redux (actually, I had it bookmarked already :))

Comment: This seems to contradict the other answers - assuming `use-context-selector` "actually works" and in a meaningful way (i.e. reducing un-necessary renders)

Comment: No, this answer is definitely correct :)  Last time I checked, the `useContextSelector` lib works by hacking around its normal behavior.  It uses the undocumented `unstable_changedBits` option to force the context consumers to _never_ actually update as they normally would, then uses subscriptions to bypass the normal rendering flow and trigger additional re-renders.  Please read my post [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/) to understand how context usually works.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20646
Check this 
and this
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20890

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of those PRs. They also didn't exist when I wrote that answer a year ago, or this latest comment 6 months ago :)  It's also worth noting that as of today, those PRs are only internal to FB's build, there's no timeline for releasing that publicly, and it's likely that the API approach for those will change in some way.  So, it's going to happen _eventually_, but no details on when or exactly how it will work.

Answer (score 12):

As [markerikson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741917/559913) answers, it is not possible, but you can **work around** it without using external dependencies and without falling back to doing manual subscriptions.

As a workaround, you can *let the component re-render, but skip the VDOM reconciliation* by **memoizing the returned React element with `useMemo`.**

```
function Section(props) {
  const partOfState = selectPartOfState(useContext(StateContext))

  // Memoize the returned node
  return useMemo(() => {
    return <div>{partOfState}</div>
  }, [partOfState])
}
```

This is because internally, when React diffs 2 versions of virtual DOM nodes, if it encountered the exact same reference, it will skip reconciling that node entirely.

Comment: wow, never thought of that, thanks. While the parent component would still go through the render, all child would stay as is, this could be observed with react browser plugin

Answer (score 7):

Solution with external store (Redux or Zustand like approach) with new hook `useSyncExternalStore` comes with React 18.

For **React 18**: Define `createStore` and `useStore` functions:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useSyncExternalStore } from "react";

const createStore = (initialState) => {
  let state = initialState;
  const getState = () => state;
  const listeners = new Set();
  const setState = (fn) => {
    state = fn(state);
    listeners.forEach((l) => l());
  };
  const subscribe = (listener) => {
    listeners.add(listener);
    return () => listeners.delete(listener);
  };
  return { getState, setState, subscribe };
};

const useStore = (store, selector) =>
  useSyncExternalStore(
    store.subscribe,
    useCallback(() => selector(store.getState()), [store, selector])
  );
```

Now use it :

```
const store = createStore({ count: 0, text: "hello" });

const Counter = () => {
  const count = useStore(store, (state) => state.count);
  const inc = () => {
    store.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, count: prev.count + 1 }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {count} <button onClick={inc}>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For **React 17** and any React version that supports hooks:

- **Option 1:** You may use the external library (maintained by React team)
  [`use-sync-external-store/shim`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sync-external-store) :

```js
import { useSyncExternalStore } from "use-sync-external-store/shim";
```

- **Option 2:** If you don't want to add new library and don't care about concurency problems:

```js
const createStore = (initialState) => {
  let state = initialState;
  const getState = () => state;
  const listeners = new Set();
  const setState = (fn) => {
    state = fn(state);
    listeners.forEach((l) => l());
  }
  const subscribe = (listener) => {
    listeners.add(listener);
    return () => listeners.delete(listener);
  }
  return {getState, setState, subscribe}
}

const useStore = (store, selector) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => selector(store.getState()));
  useEffect(() => {
    const callback = () => setState(selector(store.getState()));
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(callback);
    callback();
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [store, selector]);
  return state;
}
```

Sources:

- [A conference talk from **Daishi Kato** from **React Conf 2021**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPfSC5bQPR8)
- [A blog post about same conference talk by **Chetan Gawai**](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/12/30/react-18-usesyncexternalstore-api)

Answer (score 6):

I created a toolkit for managing state using ContextAPI. It provides `useSelector` (with autocomplete) as well as `useDispatch`.

### The library is available here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-toolkit
- https://github.com/bergkvist/react-context-toolkit

It uses:

- [use-context-selector](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector) to avoid unneccesary rerenders.
- [`createSlice` from @reduxjs/toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/docs/api/createSlice.md) to make the state more modular and to avoid boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

I've created this small package, [react-use-context-selector](https://github.com/mohebifar/react-use-context-selector), and it just does the job.

I used the same approach as used in Redux's useSelector. It also comes with type declarations and the return type matches the selector function's return type making it suitable for using in TS project.

```
function MyComponent() {
  // This component will re-render only when the `name` within the context object changes.
  const name = useContextSelector(context, value => value.name);

  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on this problem:
I used the function as child pattern with useMemo to create a generic selector component:

```
import React, {
  useContext,
  useReducer,
  createContext,
  Reducer,
  useMemo,
  FC,
  Dispatch
} from "react";
export function createStore<TState>(
  rootReducer: Reducer<TState, any>,
  initialState: TState
) {
  const store = createContext({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: (() => {}) as Dispatch<any>
  });
  const StoreProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, initialState);
    return (
      <store.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</store.Provider>
    );
  };
  const Connect: FC<{
    selector: (value: TState) => any;
    children: (args: { dispatch: Dispatch<any>; state: any }) => any;
  }> = ({ children, selector }) => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(store);
    const selected = selector(state);
    return useMemo(() => children({ state: selected, dispatch }), [
      selected,
      dispatch,
      children
    ]);
  };
  return { StoreProvider, Connect };
}
```

Counter component:

```
import React, { Dispatch } from "react";

interface CounterProps {
  name: string;
  count: number;
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
}
export function Counter({ name, count, dispatch }: CounterProps) {
  console.count("rendered Counter " + name);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Counter {name}: {count}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch("INCREMENT_" + name)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
import React, { Reducer } from "react";
import { Counter } from "./counter";
import { createStore } from "./create-store";
import "./styles.css";
const initial = { counterA: 0, counterB: 0 };
const counterReducer: Reducer<typeof initial, any> = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "INCREMENT_A": {
      return { ...state, counterA: state.counterA + 1 };
    }
    case "INCREMENT_B": {
      return { ...state, counterB: state.counterB + 1 };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
const { Connect, StoreProvider } = createStore(counterReducer, initial);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Connect selector={(state) => state.counterA}>
          {({ dispatch, state }) => (
            <Counter name="A" dispatch={dispatch} count={state} />
          )}
        </Connect>
        <Connect selector={(state) => state.counterB}>
          {({ dispatch, state }) => (
            <Counter name="B" dispatch={dispatch} count={state} />
          )}
        </Connect>
      </div>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
}
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-selector-6v7jm?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say it's not possible. For example, if you have an array, you cannot select in Context one element of the array while in Redux you can. It's for this reason that [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices) integrates the use of Redux in its implementation. In that way you can define either Redux slices or React Context slices seamlessly. This is how you do it:

```js
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices";

export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  slices:{
    count1: { // Redux slice
      initialState: 0,
      reducers:{
        increment: (state) => state + 1
      }
    },
    count2: { // React Context slice
      initialArg: 0
    },
    todos: { // Redux slice
      initialState: [],
      reducers: {
        add: (state, {payload}) => {
          state.push(payload);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can use them in your component with the `useSlice` hook:

```js
// app.jsx
import {useSlice} from "./slices";

const App = () => {
  const [count1, reduxDispatch, {increment}] = useSlice("count1");
  const [count2, setCount2] = useSlice("count2");
  const [todos, , {add}] = useSlice("todos");
  const [firstTodo] = useSlice("todos", state => state[0]);

  return <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => reduxDispatch(increment())}>+</button>{count1}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount2(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count2}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => reduxDispatch(add("use react-context-slices"))}>add</button>
      {todos.map((t,i) => <div key={i}>{t}</div>)}
    </div>
    <div>{firstTodo}</div>
  </>
};

export default App;
```

As you see with this library it's extremely easy to integrate both Redux and React Context slices seamlessly with zero-boilerplate. It's for this reason that [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices) library should be considered an ultimate solution to global state management in React.

Answer (score 0):

Using selectors with plain react context is not possible. If your state saved in the context is reactive, i-e using `useState` to hold the state values. React will case re-render for the whole component tree down from the provider. Now, there are many libraries that solve this problem. But if you really want your state values to be stored in react context and be able to use selectors for fine grained reactivity. I have built a library called [textcon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textcon). It uses react context under the hood to provide access to the state via a provider component but instead of relying on `useState` for reactivity, it relies on signals and subscriptions and let react's `useSyncExternalStore` handle the sync between the state and react components.
Here is the link to github repo -> https://github.com/mabdullahadeel/textcon
If you want some explanation of how to use, I've written medium article about it. https://medium.com/@abdadeel/using-selectors-with-react-context-textcon-af34cb74e822