# Why is react re-rendering/updating all components in the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react application which uses Material UI v5. I do not have any styling and am using the default `TextField` component to test the rendering issue. In my page, I have only a `Typography`, `Breadcrumb`, `IconButton` and `TextField`. To replicate the issue, I have put one controlled TextField and about six other uncontrolled TextFields. When I start writing on the controlled TextField, all the components inside page starts re-rendering. And if I start typing a lot/faster, it sometimes freezes or takes a while (like 500-1000ms) to render the text inside the TextField. Basically it freezes for a second or half.

Here is a [replicated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-kirch-1ggnq?file=/src/App.js) of what I have. My real project is also using create-react-app. I have the same thing in my react app and it renders everything. Here is a [link](https://ibb.co/jHDyQq7) to a snap taken. I used the react developer tools profilers "Highlight updates when components render" option.

My Environment details:

```
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
Binaries:
Node: 14.17.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.22.11 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 7.20.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Browsers:
Chrome: Not Found
Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1023.0), Chromium (93.0.961.52)
npmPackages:
@emotion/react: ^11.4.1 => 11.4.1
@emotion/styled: ^11.3.0 => 11.3.0
@mui/core: 5.0.0-alpha.47
@mui/icons-material: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
@mui/lab: ^5.0.0-alpha.47 => 5.0.0-alpha.47
@mui/material: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
@mui/private-theming: 5.0.0
@mui/styled-engine: 5.0.0
@mui/styled-engine-sc: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
@mui/styles: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
@mui/system: 5.0.0
@mui/types: 7.0.0
@mui/utils: 5.0.0
@types/react: 17.0.22
react: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-dom: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2
styled-components: ^5.3.1 => 5.3.1
```

Is this the react behavior? Can I stop re-rendering/updating of all components when one component updates its state?

Comment: `Is this the react behavior?` Yes. It just depends where you put state. You can use [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to prevent unnecessary renders (if you know how to use it correctly), but I'd first start by restructuring components and putting state only where it's needed.

Comment: So suppose I had a page with multiple fields or form elements such as checkbox, radio buttons etc. And I wanted to update the value of the text field in to a state. That would mean that everything visible there would re-render correct?

Comment: It depends where you put your state, how you access it, and your general component structure. You can definitely cause components not to re-render if you use context and children appropriately (e.g. this falls under component structure) as well. I feel like reaching for React.memo is an "I don't know how the hell else to fix this problem" solution, personally.

Comment: The last statement is exactly why I’m trying to understand how to restructure the components better. Slapping in memo and calling it a day seems like the last thing I’d do

Comment: Can you perhaps point me to a sample code or project where you’d consider a good structure usage?

Comment: Check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-moser-ygz15?file=/src/App.js `children` is a very powerful prop. I moved the state to `MyFormContextProvider` and now you can see that App and all of it's "helper" components like IconButton, the breadcrumbs, etc no longer render when a value is changed. The downside of context is that React still hasn't implemented context selectors to have really fine grained rendering control (like we have with redux out of the box), but it's not bad. And honestly, it's really easy to implement redux like state with a store and subscribe function.

Comment: Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741558/implement-useselector-equivalent-for-react-context) for interesting homebrewed solutions to prevent re-renders (and some commentary from the maintainer of react-redux!)  and some commentary from the react-redux maintainer! Also this one: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/73

Comment: This helped. Thank you! Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0):

React components are made using a rule called decomposition. Each component can have a father and a child (if not alone) and can be modeled as shown in this picture.
[React component tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzfpb.png)

When the state is updated in the parent component, to update the screen, this component is rendered and also all the child components are rendered in it.

if you want to prevent this behavior in a class component you need to use shouldComponentUpdate you can read its doc in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and if you want to handle it in a functional component you can use useMemo hook, and you can read its doc in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate)